# Is the primary implementation of *any* popular programming language interpreter written in C++?

Tags: c++, c, interpreter

At the moment I am considering whether or not to rewrite a programming language interpreter that I maintain in C++. The interpreter is currently implemented in C.

But I was wondering, is the *primary* implementation—because, certainly, people have made versions of many interpreters using a language other than the one used by the original authors—of any *popular* programming language interpreter currently in use today written in C++?

And, if not, is there a good reason for not writing an interpreter in C++? It is my understanding that C++ code, if written correctly, can be very portable and can potentially compile to run just as fast as compiled C code that does the same thing.

Comment: Your interpreter runs?  Is stable?  Used by people?  Why rewrite it all?

Comment: If you already have a C implementation, that is an excellent reason not to rewrite it in C++.

Comment: Certainly, my interpreter runs, but there a number of problems with it---in particular, clumsy symbol-handling and numerous memory leaks. These flaws are such that I believe the best way to address them is to rewrite the interpreter from scratch. Given that the only two real contenders for the rewrite language are C and C++, I am wondering whether C++ would be the better language to implement the interpreter in, considering that it provides (what seem to be) more intuitive facilities for memory management and string processing.

Comment: +1 for not thinking that C and C++ are basically the same.

Comment: Do you know C++ as well as you know C. Do you know C++ well enough to write your program without spending much of your time learning idioms and the best ways to achieve your goal? In essence, will you be learning C++ whilst doing this rewrite? If so then IMHO you should stick to your C implementation unless you want to potentially rewrite again once you know what you're doing.

Comment: If you have a working C implementation, that's an excellent starting point to rewrite it in C++.

Comment: You may be interested in these slides: http://airs.com/ian/cxx-slides.pdf

Comment: Your first question is only answerable by reference to the source code. I wrote a production interpreter in C in the 1980s and if I was doing it today I would certainly do it in C++ or even Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote an interpreter in C++ (after many in C over the years) and I think that C++ is a decent language for that. About the implementation I only would travel back in time and change my choice of implementing the possibility to have several different interpreters running at the same time (every one multithreaded) simply because it made the code more complex and it's something that was never used. Multithreading is quite useful, but multiple instances of the interpreter was pointless...

However now my big regret is indeed the **very fact I wrote that interpreter** because now it's used in production with a fairly amount of code written and persons trained for it, and because the language is quite uglier and less powerful that python... but switching to python now would add costs. It has no bugs known to me... but yet it's worse than python and this is a bug (in addition to the error already made of paying the cost of writing it for no reason).

I simply should have used python initially instead (or lua or any other ready made interpreter that can easily be embedded and that has a reasonable licensing)... my only excuse for this is that I didn't know about python or lua at that time.

While writing an interpreter is a funny thing to do as a programming exercise I'd suggest you to avoid writing your own for production, especially (please don't take it personally) if the care that low level complexity requires is out of your reach (I find for example the presence of several memory leaks quite shocking).

C++ is still a low level language and while you can get some help for example on the memory handling side still the **main assumption of the language is that your code is 100% right** as no runtime error is going to help you (only undefined behaviour daemons).

If you missed this assumption of 100% correct code for C (a much simpler language) then I don't see how can you be confident you'll write correct code in C++ (a complexity monster in comparison). I suspect you would just end up with another buggy interpreter that you'll have to throw away.

Comment: I disagree about writing buggy in C++. C++ is typesafe (no `void*` around) and allows idioms such as RAII to manage resources. These 2 features make it MUCH easier to write non-buggy code in my opinion. Truth to be told, I think the more error-prone features actually come from C...

Comment: Sorry but I think you're completely wrong on this. C++ biggest problem is complexity and that doesn't come from C.

Also a serious problem is that it may **look** like an high-level language while indeed it isn't, and if you don't understand the implication then you're going to suffer a lot with C++.

It's very easy to write C++ code that looks nice and that instead is just a ticking time bomb... for example `v.push_back(v.back());` to add to a non-empty vector a copy of the last element.

In C++ there are many of such traps. And for sure it's not K&R fault.

Comment: Well, I didn't write the interpreter originally; I "adopted" it from someone else, so many of the memory leaks and other problems were already present. I succeeded in removing some, but overall the whole implementation is still a big mess---not because the original author was a bad programmer, but because the interpreter represents over ten years of evolution.

Comment: @Thomas things are then different... I would try to compare X=(cost of rewrite and re-debug + future cost for scripts because of the poor language) with
Y=(cost of embedding python and converting scripts (or writing a converter) + training of programmers).  C++ for writing an interpreter is in my opinion ok compared to C... for example C++ exceptions are in an interpreter nice to use for runtime errors because there is a clear logical "boundary" about state (being able to catch and swallow an exception in a general "sprinkled state" C++ program is IMO much harder to do correctly).

Answer (score 5):

If you wrote the current implementation and -as you say in your comment- it has:

> clumsy symbol-handling and numerous
>   memory leaks

Then rewriting in c++ is not going to help you. First try to understand why the current implementation goes wrong. On the other hand, if you are not the original developer then just choose whichever language you know best and port.

**Update:**
I think [sth's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185593/is-the-primary-implementation-of-any-popular-programming-language-interpreter-w/3185748#3185748) explains properly why many languages are implemented in C rather than C++. On the topic of complete rewrites, [heed the words of Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not the original developer. The interpreter, as it stands, represents about 10--15 years of evolution, hence why its code is so messy in places. I'm fairly convinced that the only practical way to address all of its flaws is to rewrite it from scratch in either C or C++; but I'm wondering why there are, or at least seem to be, no popular interpreters written in C++. But then, of course, there's always a first time. ;-)

Comment: I didn't think you had written the original. I updated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many are. IIRC the Hotspot Java VM is written in C++, Haskells ghc, ...

As many here have noted You should really have a look at [LLVM](http://www.llvm.org/), it is a toolkit for building compiler, interpreter and virtual machines. You basically do the frontend work, (i.e. parsing your language + semantic analysis + codegen in LLVM IR) and LLVM will immediately give you building for different platforms, jit, optimization, compiling to native code, ...
It also has some tools for parsing and AST, and error handling and notification (but maybe that is part of the Clang subproject.)

Comment: Note: All this is second hand knowledge. AFAIK only a part, or the reference implementation is written in Haskell, to generate optimized programs you need either a gcc or a LLVM backend, which is then written in C or C++ respectively. See here: [Fast Haskell using LLVM](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/smoking-fast-haskell-code-using-ghcs-new-llvm-codegen/)

Comment: GHC compiler is written in Haskell, GHC's run-time system is written in C, not C++.

Answer (score 2):

Most popular programming languages started to be created before there were many good C++ compilers available. Therefore the primary interpreters of those languages did not start out in C++, and once you have put a lot of work into a working interpreter, you usually don't throw that away just because it could now also be written in C++.

And if you start a new project for a interpreter written in C++ it is has to go a long way to become the *primary* implementation.

Comment: Using LLVM might help (and that's c++).

Comment: @Klaim: Yeah, for example clang is a serious compiler for C/C++/Objective-C, based on LLVM and written in C++, but one can hardly claim that it is the *primary* compiler for those languages...

Comment: One can hardly claim that *any* compiler for those languages is "primary".

Comment: And I was mor thinking about newer languages like D. In fact it's recommanded to start with LLVM for any new language compiler.

Comment: One fundamental difference between compilers and interpreters, however, is the latter's far greater need for speed and efficiency. Certainly, no one wants to be sitting around all day waiting for a program to compile, but if the result is well-optimised and runs quickly once it's been compiled, people aren't really going to complain. But an interpreter has to run a program from scratch every time is is executed, so speed is a real concern; the "compilation" step (whether the program is compiled into bytecode, an abstract syntax tree, or whatever) really effects the overall run-time speed.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome V8 Javascript Engine Implements ECMA-262 and it's extremely fast. Maybe you could rewrite it in C++ but you shold think about other features like implement a bytecode specification instead rewriting your automates in C++. Rewrite it will just help to organize the code (which is a great thing for group working), but nothing in performance.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU foundation has just recently announced that all the new versions of gcc will be written in c++.

Comment: @spongL http://allanmcrae.com/2010/06/gcc-in-cxx/
The adoption/conversion will be slow and not done in "c++ for c++ sake" but it will eventually happen.

Comment: I believe <http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00705.html> is the thread that announced that they've decided to *allow* C++ in the GCC code, that does *not* mean it's going to be rewritten. That would be insane, IMO.

Comment: It's too late now for GCC. In face of Clang, i guess they will slowly abandon GCC.

Comment: @litb: Its going to be egcc all over again, though this time, GCC will most likely be retired permenently, I just hope some of the ego-farts from GCC don't make it into the clang ranks.

Comment: @litb "they" who? guys at fsf? @Hippicoder if the "ego-farts" from gcc are good programmers, why shouldn't they go to clang ranks? (they should respect the design, guidelines and whatever of clang anyway)

Comment: Irrelevant. *gcc* is not an interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

[Tamarin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarin_(JavaScript_engine)) - Adobe and Mozilla ECMAScript interpreter is written in C++. Being the one for which the original language author has responsibility, it might be considered the primary one (IIRC the ECMA reference implementation is written in OCaml, but that isn't actually used except as a reference)

Answer (score 0):

Sun's Java implementation seems to be written in C++ mostly.

Answer (score 0):

If memory leaks are your only problem with your current program then try valgrind on it. I've never had a memory leak in my software that valgrind could not track down for me. In fact it has saved my butt on so many occasions.

Here is a tutorial

http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html

Comment: Valgrind is a very useful tool, but in the interpreter I adopted (1) the memory leaks would require far-reaching, "radical" fixes, fixes that would require me to rewrite parts of the code anyway and risk messing up parts of the program (potentially causing dangling pointers, etc.), and (2) memory leaks aren't the only problem; there are a pile of changes to symbol handling that I want to make and the existing system is too complicated to change safely, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can (or want) to give this a blanket "yes". I think it's a matter of pragmatism combined with needs of the individual language, and also depends on whether it is a compiled language (or bytecode-compiled) or interpreted, or...

If you are trying to write cross-platform code, you will find that the lowest common denominator is usually a C compiler (due to different CPU architectures, assemblers are not suitable for deploying to many platforms). Since C++ was coded to sit on top of most C infrastructure (like using name mangling to fit type overloads into something a C linker understands), it is usually the lowest-common-denominator OO language that's available even on embedded systems. That makes it a popular choice for people who want to write their language in a high-level, maintainable fashion.

Also, most programming languages have a reason for existing, want to solve problems in a different way (better necessarily means different, after all), which means they have rather unusual needs regarding what their code needs to be able to do, and don't use a lot of the support facilities another implementation language offers, because they wouldn't have enough control over it. So given you'll want to reimplement a lot of e.g. the object model and data types anyway, the low-level aspects of C++ actually are an advantage.

That said, many languages start out with their first version written in C++, a first simple compiler for instance, and then write the next version in that simple version ("bootstrapping"). This has the advantage that you can use your own language to extend it. To port it, they then modify only their compiler to cross-compile to the desired platform, then build the compiler with this cross-compiler, and the result is a native version of the full language for the new platform.

The languages that tend to not do this are usually mainly the scripting languages, which tend to remain as interpreted C++-implemented languages (Though others have mentioned popular exceptions).

Another common reason to pick C++ is existing infrastructure. E.g. if you want to bind to existing system frameworks, you often need to drop down to C++, or if you want to take advantage of existing compiler backends (like LLVM, which is written in C++), or even if they only use C, often C++ is the most suitable OO-like implementation language that can easily talk to the C parts of a system.

So the question you want to ask yourself is likely: What are my needs, and what language best suits those?

Some languages are simply preprocessors on another language (C++ and Objective-C both started out as preprocessors on top of C). They add their own syntax or features, translate those into the implementation language, then compile that modified code using an existing compiler. If a language already does all you want, that may be a better approach, and let you leverage the experience of the engineers working on that other language, combining your work-hours into more than you alone could provide.